# Android - Enabling and Disabling Bluetooth - SDK 3 (OS 1.5) - programatically?

Tags: android

I have written code to enable and disable various things programatically like Wifi, Ringer modes, Airplane modes.  All things that you would see in a power toggle widget.

The one that I have not found out how to do is bluetooth.  It appears that in SDK level 3 (OS 1.5) there is no pretty bluetooth manager class.  Has anyone pinpointed any good source examples on enabling and disabling bluetooth that will also be forwards compatible with users running 2.0 (Droid) / 2.1 (Nexus)?

I have found a few partial examples in my google searches that I could not get to actually run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

This has alot of great examples and teaches you the basic gist of starting up bluetooth and getting sockets.

You should probably read the whole thing but just for a quick starter look at the section called "Setting Up Bluetooth"

Comment: That is all for SDK level 5 (2.0) and not SDK 3 (1.5) which is what we are needing here.  The link you provided revolves around the BluetoothAdapter class which doesn't exist in SDK 3.